# Android Settings API turn on bluetooth to improve location accuracy?

Tags: android, bluetooth, gps, geolocation

I have use new Settings API to turn on GPS without to leave my application.
My LocationRequest looks like this:

LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

everything works fine but dialog prompts me to enable bluetooth too (along with GPS) Is there way to only enable GPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that in your LocationSettingsRequest you are mistakenly requesting BLE support.

LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
     .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequestHighAccuracy)
     .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequestBalancedPowerAccuracy);

> builder.setNeedBle(true);

If the client is using BLE scans to derive location, it can request that BLE be enabled by calling setNeedBle(boolean):

If you **do not want BLE then set this to false** or remove this line.

Answer (score 0):

I found the same issue here. And I have to find a walk around this by first turn on bluetooth in an intent and then from the callback to request location.

```
private boolean isBluetoothEnabled() {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter != null && !mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```